# At what point of the curve given by $f (t)$ does the tangent line intersect the $z$-axis?

Tags: calculus, multivariable-calculus

At what point of the curve given by $f (t) = (3t^2 − 6, 2t + 3, 7t^2 + 4t + 1)$ does the tangent line intersect the $z$-axis?

I tried the following:
If $M$ is the desired point then $M = f(t_0)$ for some $t_0$. 
 $f'(t) = (6t,2,14t+4) \implies f'(t_0)=(6t_0,2,14t_0+4)$. I have no idea after this.

Comment: If this were in $2D$ you could do it, yeah? You have the slope at the point $t_0$ and you have the point $t_0$ so you can get the equation of the line. How would you extrapolate this to $3D$?

Comment: If one of the answers below answered your question, the way this site works works, you'd "accept" the answer, more here: [What should I do when someone answers my question?](https://stackoverflow.com/help/someone-answers). But only if your question really has been answered. If not, consider adding more details to the question.

Answer (score 1):

The directional vector of the line is given by $f'(t)$. Then your tangent line at a point $t_0$ will be given by the equation

$g(\lambda)=f(t_0)+\lambda f'(t_0)=(3t_0^2-6,2t_0+3,7t_0^2+4t_0+1)+\lambda(6t_0,2,14t_0+4)=(3t_0^2+6\lambda t_0-6,2t_0+2\lambda+3,7t_0^2+4t_0+14\lambda t_0+4\lambda+1)$.

To see when this equation intersects the Z-axis we have to set the first and second components equal to $0$. So

$3t_0^2+6\lambda t_0-6=0$

$2t_0+2\lambda+3=0\Rightarrow \lambda=\dfrac{-3-2t_0}{2}$

So substituting in the first equation we get

$3t_0^2+6\left(\dfrac{-3-2t_0}{2}\right)t_0-6=-3t_0^2-9t_0-6=0\Rightarrow t_0=-2,t_0=-1$.

And thus $\lambda=\dfrac{1}{2},\lambda=-\dfrac{1}{2}$.

So the points where the tangent line of the curve intersects the Z-axis are

$(0,0,9)$ and $(0,0,9)$, which is obviously just one point.

There are two distinct tangent lines (each one of them tangent to the curve at two distinct points) that intersect the Z-axis, but the two of them do it at the same point.

Comment: $f'(t)$ only describes the slope at the point $t$. The equation for the tangent line is different. Your answer is wrong

Comment: You were right. I gotta get some sleep. I corrected it already.